# Merging records from multiple rows in table sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have some dirty resource usage records in `t_resourcetable` which looks like this

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-03 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-04 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

I need those dirty rows to be merged in such way

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

This should get updated to the same table. I have more than 40k rows so cannot use a cursor. Please help me clean up this through more optimized sql statements.

Solution provided does not encounter the scenario like

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-03 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-04 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        2        2012-01-14 10:09:00.000          2012-01-15 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-15 00:00:00.000          2012-01-16 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-16 00:00:00.000          2012-01-16 03:00:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

I need those dirty rows to be merged in such way

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        2        2012-01-14 10:09:00.000          2012-01-16 03:00:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

Please assist me with this dirty data problem.

Comment: What sql version are you using?

Comment: explain what condition u use to filter?

Comment: What are the rules for merging? That's a good place to start.

Comment: Do you want to merge consecutive time intervals, or all intervals with same resNo/subres? Are they the same?

Comment: yes based on resource subres i need to combine particular record starttime and endtime and club. and update it to one record like resno 1 and subres 2 clubbed in 1 row from 3

Comment: @steavefinner Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005 you could do something like this:

```
create table #temp
(
  resNo int,
  subres int,
  enddate datetime,
  primary key (resNo, subres)
)

-- Store the values you need for enddate in a temp table
insert into #temp
select resNo, 
       subres,
       max(enddate) as enddate
from t_resourcetable
group by resNo, subres

-- Delete duplicates keeping the row with min startdate
delete T
from (
        select row_number() over(partition by resNo, subres order by startdate) as rn
        from t_resourcetable
     ) as T
where rn > 1

-- Set enddate where needed
update T set enddate = tmp.enddate
from t_resourcetable as T
  inner join #temp as tmp
    on T.resNo = tmp.resNo and
       t.subres = tmp.subres
where T.enddate <> tmp.enddate

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 6):

```
MERGE INTO t_resourcetable AS TARGET
USING (
    SELECT
        resNo, subres,
        MIN(startdate) as startdate,
        MAX(enddate) as enddate
    FROM t_resourcetable
    GROUP BY resNo, subres
) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.resNo = SOURCE.resNo
AND TARGET.subres = SOURCE.subres
AND TARGET.startdate = SOURCE.startdate
-- Set enddate on the first record in the group
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TARGET.enddate = SOURCE.enddate
-- Delete the remaining items
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

---

**Edit:** To respect the gaps in the intervals:

```
MERGE INTO t_resourcetable AS TARGET
USING (
    -- Find the first item in each interval group
    SELECT
        resNo, subres, startdate,
        row_number() over (partition by resNo, subres order by startdate) as rn
    FROM t_resourcetable t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        -- No other intervals that intersect this from behind
        SELECT NULL
        FROM t_resourcetable t2
        WHERE t2.resNo = t1.resNo
        AND t2.subres = t1.subres
        AND t2.startdate < t1.startdate
        AND t2.enddate >= t1.startdate
    )
) AS SOURCE_start
INNER JOIN (
    -- Find the last item in each interval group
    SELECT
        resNo, subres, enddate,
        row_number() over (partition by resNo, subres order by startdate) as rn
    FROM t_resourcetable t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        -- No other intervals that intersect this from ahead
        SELECT NULL
        FROM t_resourcetable t2
        WHERE t2.resNo = t1.resNo
        AND t2.subres = t1.subres
        AND t2.startdate <= t1.enddate
        AND t2.enddate > t1.enddate
    )
) AS SOURCE_end
    ON SOURCE_start.resNo = SOURCE_end.resNo
    AND SOURCE_start.subres = SOURCE_end.subres
    AND SOURCE_start.rn = SOURCE_end.rn -- Join by row number
ON TARGET.resNo = SOURCE_start.resNo
AND TARGET.subres = SOURCE_start.subres
AND TARGET.startdate = SOURCE_start.startdate
-- Set enddate on the first record in the group
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TARGET.enddate = SOURCE_end.enddate
-- Delete the remaining items
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

Result:

```
resNo   subres   startdate          enddate
    1        2   2012-01-02 22:03   2012-01-04 16:23
    1        2   2012-01-14 10:09   2012-01-16 03:00
    1        3   2012-01-06 16:23   2012-01-06 22:23
    2        2   2012-01-04 05:23   2012-01-06 16:23
```

---

**Edit:** If there is any risk of concurrent edits on the target table, you might want to add the `HOLDLOCK` hint. This will prevent any primary key violation errors, and be slighty more resource effective. (Thanks Joey):

```
MERGE INTO t_resourcetable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS TARGET
...
```

Comment: Very elegant, probably efficient too! +1

Comment: Any reason to not use the HOLDLOCK hint here? See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could first store the result in a temporary table like this:

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
(
    resNo INT, 
    subres INT, 
    startdate DATETIME, 
    enddate DATETIME
)

INSERT   @tmp
SELECT   resNo, subres, MIN(startdate), MAX(enddate)
FROM     t_resourcetable
GROUP BY resNo, subres
```

To update `t_resourcetable` table you could do this:

```sql
DELETE   t_resourcetable

INSERT   t_resourcetable
SELECT   * 
FROM     @tmp
```

And run all of this in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table.
Now you can fill the temp table with the new and cleaned data.
I think, you must make a combined key with resNo and subres and select min startdate and max enddate.

At least, delete all data in the old table and fill it with data from temp table.

Comment: Tobi thanks for replying but i have tried it creating temp table and moving forward trough cursor but the performance of the query was too slow

Comment: Oh really? I think, 40k rows for sqlserver shouldn't slow down the server ;-) have you tried the example from "dillenmeister"?

Comment: my client application is in VBA and i am interacting in lan enviournment it slows down in lan