# merging records for sql table based on column data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have some dirty resource usage records in t_resourcetable which looks like this

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-03 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-04 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

i need those dirty rows to be merged in such way

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

this should get updated to the same table, i have more than 40k rows so can not use cursor please help me cleaning up this kind of data trough some optimized sql statements.

solution provided with temptable and group does not encounter the scenario like.
i am looking for without cursor based solution to this problem

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-03 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-04 00:00:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        2        2012-01-14 10:09:00.000          2012-01-15 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-15 00:00:00.000          2012-01-16 00:00:00.000
1        2        2012-01-16 00:00:00.000          2012-01-16 03:00:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

i need those dirty rows to be merged in such way

```
resNo   subres    startdate                        enddate
1        2        2012-01-02 22:03:00.000          2012-01-04 16:23:00.000
1        2        2012-01-14 10:09:00.000          2012-01-16 03:00:00.000
1        3        2012-01-06 16:23:00.000          2012-01-06 22:23:00.000
2        2        2012-01-04 05:23:00.000          2012-01-06 16:23:00.000
```

plesae take me out of this dirty data problem

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884642/merging-records-from-multiple-rows-in-table-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to create backup:

```
select * 
into t_resourcetable_backup20120327
from t_resourcetable
```

Then update enddate for first records grouped by resNo and subRes:

```
update t_resourcetable
set enddate = (select max (enddate) 
                 from t_resourcetable t1 
                where t1.resNo = t_resourcetable.resNo
                  and t1.subRes = t_resourcetable.subRes)
 where not exists (select null
                 from t_resourcetable t1
                where t1.resNo = t_resourcetable.resNo
                  and t1.subRes = t_resourcetable.subRes
                  and t1.startdate < t_resourcetable.startdate)
```

And finally remove extra records:

```
delete t_resourcetable
 where exists (select null
                 from t_resourcetable t1
                where t1.resNo = t_resourcetable.resNo
                  and t1.subRes = t_resourcetable.subRes
                  and t1.startdate < t_resourcetable.startdate)
```

This will leave duplicates if you have duplicate startdates for unique combination of resNo and subRes. You should also check if enddates always have corresponding startdates because you will lose gaps - but this might just be the thing you want.

In addition to creating backup you might wrap update/delete in transaction, do a select after delete and rollback, then check the data in Excel and, if everything seems fine, repeat the transaction but commit it this time.

**UPDATE:** this query identifies gaps. If you are on Sql Server 2000, convert CTEs to derived tables. First returns list of resources not having predecessors, last does the same for successors. Both count gaps. Then lists are joined by resNo, subRes and gap number.

```
;with first as (
    select resNo, subres, startdate,
  row_number() over (partition by resNo, subres order by startdate) rowNumber
      from t_resourcetable
     where not exists (select null
                       from t_resourcetable t1
                      where t1.resNo = t_resourcetable.resNo
                        and t1.subres = t_resourcetable.subres
                        and t1.enddate = t_resourcetable.startdate)
),
last as (
  select resNo, subres, enddate,
  row_number () over (partition by resNo, subres order by enddate) rowNumber
  from t_resourcetable
     where not exists (select null
                       from t_resourcetable t1
                      where t1.resNo = t_resourcetable.resNo
                        and t1.subres = t_resourcetable.subres
                        and t1.startdate = t_resourcetable.enddate)
)
select first.resno, first.subres, first.startdate, last.enddate
from first 
  inner join last
  on first.resNo = last.resNo
    and first.subres = last.subres
    and first.rowNumber = last.rowNumber
```

Comment: this would not return two rows for resource 1 and subresource 2 which is starting on 1-(2/1/2012-4/1/2012) 2-(14/1/2012-16/1/2012). rather this will result only one row (2/1/2012-16/1/2012) as continuous resource usage thanks for your reply nikola

Comment: @steavefinner did you try it? I don't think it would take a lot of time providing that you have an index on resno and subres.

Answer (score 1):

you need to group your data by resNo and subRes like this:

```
select resNo, subRes, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from  t_resourcetable
group by resNo, subRes
```

and insert the result on a temporary table.

Then you can truncate t_resourcetable and insert the reult from the temp tample into it

Comment: it will not work because the data for resource 1 is used two times and group by will return only one row where as actual result should have 2 rows for resourceno(1) and subres(2)

Comment: it is grouping by these two fields: resNo, subRes

Comment: yes it is by grouping these two fields resno,subres, by grouping it creates one record for two different uses of same resources at twice on different dates. ideally it should be two rows

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ?

```
SELECT resno,
       subres,
       startdate,
       MIN(enddate) AS enddate
FROM   (SELECT t1.resno,
               t1.subres,
               t1.startdate,
               t2.enddate
        FROM   t_resourcetable t1,
               t_resourcetable t2
        WHERE  t1.enddate <= t2.enddate
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM   t_resourcetable t3
                               WHERE  ( t1.resno = t3.resno
                                        AND t1.subres = t3.subres
                                        AND t1.startdate > t3.startdate
                                        AND t1.startdate <= t3.enddate )
                                       OR ( t2.resno = t3.resno
                                            AND t2.subres = t3.subres
                                            AND t2.enddate >= t3.startdate
                                            AND t2.enddate < t3.enddate )))t
GROUP  BY resno,
          subres,
          startdate
```

The image is like

[image: TimeLine]